# Fill in Line doesn't display the image

Tags: c#

This is my code :

```
 Line line2 = new Line
   {
       X1 = line.X2,
       Y1 = line.Y2,
       X2 = line.X2 + (line.X2 - line.X1 + 25),
       Y2 = line.Y2 + (line.Y2 - line.Y1 + 25),
       Fill = (new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"img.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)))),
       StrokeThickness = 20
   };
```

I'm trying to display the image "img.png" as a texture for the line but it doesn't work.

I tried it with Ellipse or Rectangle objects and it works.

Comment: Can you share error?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sry i'm not very good for asking something :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your line doesn't enclose any area then the fill brush will not be applied. Perhaps you meant to assign the `ImageBrush` to the `Stroke` property of the `Line`?